# Magento cache custom phtml page

Tags: php, magento-1.7

I want to add a cache to my custom `phtml` page.

I built a module that show a custom PHP page. But that code will not cache default by Magento cache. I need to add it, but I don't now how and I can not find the answer on the internet.

The page will show right, but very very slow, so thats why I need to cache it.

My module looks like this:

- `app/design/frontend/gaveaktie/default/template/magazijnplanning/view.phtml` (this is the PHP code)
- `app/design/frontend/gaveaktie/default/layout/test.xml`
- `app/etc/modules/Test_Test.xml`
- `app/code/local/Test/Test/controllers/IndexController.php`
- `app/code/local/Test/Test/etc/config.xml`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create the block class for your template (`Test_Test_Block_View`) and make sure that you set correct caching variables. You can find more info [here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/block_cache_and_html_ouput).